# how to write constructor prototype for a struct in a class

Tags: c++, struct, constructor

I created a class `BST` and I am facing problem in creating constructor of a struct `node` in it.

```
class BST{
    private:
    struct node{
        int key;
        node* left;
        node* right;    
    };
    node* root;
    public:
        //constructor for BST
        BST();
        //constructor for node
        node(int x);
    };
```

I get an error expected unqualified-id before 'int'.
So,I read what is an unqualified-id but didn't understand why is it needed here.

Comment: Constructors need to be declared within their respective class or struct.  Yours is declared outside the `node` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors for classes and structs must be declared within the definition of the class/struct.  Your version does not do this, as `node(int)` is declared outside the `node` class.

Change your code to this:

```
class BST
{
    private:
    struct node
    {
        int key;
        node* left;
        node* right;    
        node(int x);  
    };
    node* root;
    public:
        BST();
};
```

Then if you decide to implement the `node` constructor outside of the `BST` class:

```
BST::node::node(int x) 
{
   // code here
}
```

Comment: That perfectly answers my question.  can you also answer how should I write the first line of  `//code here` if I want to write `node*n = new node;`

Comment: The constructor you wrote requires an `int` argument.  You can't instantiate a `node` without an `int` argument.  Maybe `BST::node::node(int x) : key(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}`

Comment: I was silly for thinking of creating a node and returning it from the constructor. Now I've understood entirely. Thanks PaulMcKenzie :)